# Div issue in ul li format

Tags: html, css

I have placed a menu using `<ul> <li>` format in the div tag. inside the div i have one `<ul>` tag and the four `<li>` tags. Among the all `<li>`'s in one `![<li>][1]` i have placed the search text box. The issue here is the menu works fine in firefox but in other browsers like chrome, IE, Safari etc the text box comes below the menu. My code as follows...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#cfnavbar {
    background-image: url("images/menu_bg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 40px;
    width: 990px;
}
#cfnavbar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#cfnavbar:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#cfnavbar ul{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
float: left;
font: bold 80% Verdana;
font-size:18px;
}

#cfnavbar ul li{
display: inline;
}
#cfnavbar ul li a, #cfnavbar ul li span{
float: left;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 8px 13px 5px 6px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#cfnavbar ul li span{ 
padding-left: 0px;
}

#cfnavbar ul li a#leftcorner{
float: none;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 0px;
}

#cfnavbar ul li a#rightcorner{
padding-right: 10px;
}
#cfnavbar ul li a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
.wrapper {
    width:990px;
    background-color:#c6c6c6;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="cfnavbar">
<ul>
<li><span><a href="<?php echo $setting\['site_url'\];?>" id="leftcorner">Home Page | </a></span></li> 
<li><a href="#">Top Rated Games | </a></li> 
<li><a href="#" id="rightcorner">Top Played Games</a></li>
<li>
<div class="searchform">
    <form action="#" method="get" onsubmit="#">
    <input name="task" type="hidden" value="search" /> 
    <input name="q" type="text" size="20" id="search_textbox" value="<?php echo $search_val;?>" onclick="clickclear(this, '#" onblur="clickrecall(this,'#')" class="search_box"/> 
    <input id="box" type="image" name="submit" src="images/search.png" class="search_button" /> 
    </form>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: firefox image]

[image: other browsers image]

Comment: way too much code and also trim the images to show the relevant part....make the question concise... :)

Comment: http://www.toonkaboom.com/ .... .searchform {
 overflow:hidden;
 width:230px;
 /*margin:0 auto; */
 margin-top: 5px;
 padding:0 210px;
 
}    .search_box {
 width:193px;
 height: 25px;
 font-size: 14px;
 float:left;
 border:none;
 padding:2px 5px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#999;
 background: #000;
 margin: 0px;
 border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `display: inline` on your `<li>`s, try floating them, like this:

```
#cfnavbar ul li { float: left; }
```

You shouldn't nest block-level elements (like your search form `div`) within inline elements, as it can cause unexpected effects (and isn't valid), and floating each `<li>` will still keep them all horizontally in the same "row," which is the effect you were probably looking for.

This fixed the issue for me in Chrome. You may have to adjust a couple other things to account for the float effect, but overall it should be an improvement.

Comment: Along with adding 100% width to the `<ul>`, this works as far as I can tell in chrome on the actual site. EDIT: oh, and changing the padding from both sides to just one...

Comment: @JosephMarikle Oh yeah, just looked at his actual site; definitely he'll want to change the padding from `padding: 0 210px;` to only `padding-left: 210px;` (or right).

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting this css: `.searchform{float:right;}`
In fact `.searchform{float:left;}`  is good too

Comment: check that you have enough place. try setting the width of the searchbox and its inner elements to 10px

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell by going to the actual site, there are two things amiss.  How and why, I do not know.  First, you need to add `width:100%` to the containing `<ul>`.  This will enlarge it enough to hold the search box.  Second, you need to change the padding attribute of the `.searchform` from `padding: 0 210px;` to `padding: 0 0 0 210px;`.

Those two fixes should fix it.